# Show that a finitely generated module is trivial if it's equal to a maximal ideal times itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be any commutative ring which is local. $M$ a finitely generated $R$ module, and $ I \subset R$ a maximal ideal. How to show that $ M = IM$ $ \Longrightarrow$ $M = 0$ in an elementary way? And help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of Nakayama's Lemma?

Comment: No. Can I do it without this lemma?

Comment: No it's not quite Nakayama's lemma. To conclude $M=\{0\}$ one needs  $I$ to be a subset of the Jacobson radical. Here the best we can say is that $I$ *contains* the Jacobson radical :)

Comment: OK, with the new addition of the local hypothesis, the problem has an affirmative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be proven as stated: it is false.

Consider the field of two elements $F_2$, and look at the ring $R=F_2\times F_2$. The ideal $I=F_2\times\{0\}$ is maximal, and if we set $I=M$ we have a finitely generated $R$ module $M$. Now $IM=M$, but $M\neq \{0\}$.

---

**Edit** That was a huge omission indeed! If we add the additional condition that $R$ is local, then the unique maximal ideal is equal to the Jacobson radical, and the result is indeed true.

Suppose $M$ isn't zero and let $x_1,\ldots x_n$ is a minimal generating set for $M$. Then $x=\sum x_i\in M$, and since $IM=M$, $x=\sum x_ir_ij_i$ with $r_i\in R$ and $j_i\in I$. By rearranging that equation you get $0=\sum x_i(1-r_ij_i)$. Since $r_1j_1\in I$ and $R$ is local, $1-r_1j_1$ is a unit. But then $x_1=-\sum _{i=2}^k x_i(1-r_ij_i)(1-x_1j_1)^{-1}$, contradicting the minimality of the generating set. To avoid this contradiction, $M$ has to be zero.

Comment: @mathstarter Whenever you get stuck proving a statement, it's often worth going on a 5-10 minute excursion into thinking about counterexamples. In this case, I was able to get *really tiny* counterexample!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the condition that $R$ also is a local ring.   Is the statement true now?

Comment: @MathStarter Yes: added to the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! But why since $R$ is local, $1-r_1j_1$ is a unit?

Comment: @MathStarter Good question: if the maximal ideal is $I$, then $R\setminus I$ is the set of units of $R$. This is pretty easy to see: for every $x\in R\setminus I$, $Rx=xR=R$! (Because if this weren't the case, $Rx,xR\subseteq I$, a contradiction.) For any $i\in I$, it is impossible for $1-i$ to be in $i$. If it were, then the sum of $i$ and $1-i$ would be in $I$, and that's not possible... (see why?!)

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!